# Adjust the edge points of a rectangular shaped contour

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, mask, contour

I've got a mask with a contour that is shaped similarily to a rectangle.

[image]

I currently calculate four edge points of the contour with the help of opencv and it works fine (see blue dots on image below).

[image]

However, since the contour does sometimes contain rounded edges, the edge points are not located at the exact spot. That is why I'd like to postprocess those points. For example I could use the already generated edge points as a start to approximate lines along the four sides of the contour.

[image]

After that, I could use the four intersections of those lines as my new edge points. As shown on the image below the two edgepoints on the bottom side of the contour are already way more accurate.

[image]

Does anybody know if there's algorithms out there that can aproximate a line to the contour? Maybe its implemented in a library like opencv? Are there more smooth ways to fix this problem?

Any ideas and help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Search all near-by contour points and find the contour point that is closest (smallest distance) to your point from the edge line intersections.

Comment: Actually I do not have the edge lines as of now. I am currently working with the edge points of the second image and would like to postprocess those edge points in order to get more accurate edge points. I am struggling to generate those edge lines because there would be some approximation algorithm required and I don't know where I can find one.

Comment: Compute the curvature of every point and find those with the maximum curvature.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature. You will need the first and second derivatives. You compute those for one point on each side of the point, perhaps a few pixels away using finite differences.

Comment: You can compute the edge lines using cv2.HoughLines. Or use your initial corners to segment the contour so that you use only those contour points to fit a least squares fit of a line.

Comment: As you can see from your last image, the intersections do not lie on the contour (of the quadrilateral boundary). Once you have those intersections, you will need to find the closest point on the contour to those points, so that you get a point on the contour (if that is what you want)

Comment: For computing the first and second derivatives, see finite differences at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference

Comment: Another method to find the corners is to convert the image from cartesian to polar coordinates and find the peaks. Then convert those peaks back from polar to cartesian coordinates.  See https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_peak_local_max.html and https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html and https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga49481ab24fdaa0ffa4d3e63d14c0d5e4

Comment: For fitting to a line, see cv2.fitLine at https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gaf849da1fdafa67ee84b1e9a23b93f91f

Comment: When you finally solve this by one means or another, please post your solution/code.

Comment: just cheat, calculate a rough quad with approxPolyDP, then segment the contour points into four sets based on those rough corner points, line fit with outlier rejection to get good estimates for those lines, then intersect for "true" corners. -- OpenCV deserves a generic solution to this that does actually segment a contour or polyline into runs of straights, arcs, beziers,... given some tolerance because most polylines/contours are noisy. such a routine will probably involve iteration. what I described above is _one_ iteration of fitting (points to model) and reestimation (of model to points)

Comment: note: your first picture, the mask, isn't a clean mask. it's probably a resampled screenshot of something. even though it's a PNG, it contains values other than 0 and 255.

Comment: also note that opencv's notion of contour points is that these points are the centers of the pixels of the one-pixel white boundary line that would have to be drawn with bresenham algorithm. that's a defect of opencv that they never questioned. working with will give you "off-by-0.5" estimates of lines. one would have to artificially dilate the contour by 0.5 pixels to be exactly on the pixel edges. that (dilation/offset on polygons) can be a nontrivial operation.

Comment: Transforming to polar domain and searching for peaks, may not work well for corners with obtuse angles in the input image quadrilateral as they do not form clear peaks in the polar image.  This would be the case for your top-left and top-right corners.